# How to trigger data validation when clicking on radio button?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Microsoft Excel 2019.  I have multiple radio button groups (Form Controls) on a spreadsheet.  As shown in the picture, each cell in column B is a group.  Cell link is set to cell itself.

e.g. If "No FAC" is chosen in cell B12, value of B12 will be 1.  If "FAC" is chosen in B12, value of B12 will be 2.

Now I want to enforce data validation on B15, where the formula is =XOR((B13=B15), (B14=B15)).

The problem is, if I enter the cell value by typing the digits directly (i.e. 1 or 2), the validation will be triggered.  However, if I enter the cell value by choosing the radio button, the validation will NOT be triggered.

My question is: how to trigger data validation when I click on a radio button?  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula at `B15`

```
=XOR((B13=B15), (B14=B15))
```

seems **inconsistent** as its result would be 0 or 1. Why not you change it to?

```
=XOR((B13=B15), (B14=B15)) + 1
```

The result of this would be 1 or 2 as you expect.

Comment: Because I'm not too worried about if the value is 1 or 2.  I'm more worried about the relationship between different cells.  I see your point though.  Thanks!

Comment: The system is currently(as shown in the pic above) is in invalid state. I mean all three `B13`(input), `B14`(input) and `B15`(output) are all 1. However, from the definition of `XOR` `B15` should be 0 instead. From what I answered previously...`B15`=XOR((B13=B15), (B14=B15)) + 1 would make `B15` as 2. It seems the statement might hold true, if initialy the `B15` is set to FAC and my formula is put to use.